# Estos Errores están Conectados?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webservice, iis

Buenas tengo la siguiente inquietud tengo una aplicacion web service WFC en visual studio y funcionaba perfectamente pero donde se alojaba dicha aplicación fue migrada y me genera el siguiente error:

**El tipo de contenido text/html; charset=utf-8 del mensaje de respuesta no coincide con el tipo de contenido del enlace (text/xml; charset=utf-8).
Si usa un codificador personalizado, asegúrese de que el método IsContentTypeSupported se implemente correctamente.**

```
Los primeros 1024 bytes de la respuesta fueron:
 '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Runtime Error</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; o'. ---> System.Net.WebException: Error en el servidor remoto: (500) Error interno del servidor.
   en System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   en System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
```

Cuando reviso el logs de eventos de windows de donde se comunica mi web service pude percatarme que el erro dio por lo siguiente:

**Exception message: Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.**

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: ConfigurationErrorsException 
    Exception message: Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
   at System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, Boolean checkAptcaBit)
   at System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry.SecureGetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement)
   at System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry..ctor(String name, String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.BuildIntegratedModuleCollection(List`1 moduleList)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.GetModuleCollection(IntPtr appContext)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)

Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase)
```

He visto el siguiente link que podría brindarme una solución pero aun así no se me solventa:
[Mensaje de error después de instalar el de.NET Framework 4.0](https://support.microsoft.com/es-ve/help/2015129/error-message-after-you-install-the-net-framework-4-0-could-not-load-t)

EL ERROR DE: **El tipo de contenido text/html;** APARACE EN EL FRONT-END.

EL ERROR DE : **Exception message: Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'**.
LO ENCONTRE REVISANDO EL LOGS DE WINDOWS.

AL NO PODER CARGAR ME DA EL PRIMER MENSAJE???

Cual seria la solucion para dicho problema necesito ayuda!!

[image: El tipo de contenido text/html]

Comment: Pero de donde a donde fue migrado el servicio?

Comment: El servicio no fue migrado, lo que fue migrado fue el servidor a donde se alojaba el servicio es decir no estoy seguro en que versión estaba pero era de la viejas y lo migraron a windows server 2008

Comment: por el error lo que primero pienso es que cuando lo llamas y en el httpresponse esta mal seteado los headers, porque te marca ese tipo de error. Pero si fue una migracion deberias ver si tiene el mismo framework instalado por lo menos que no sea menor al que tenia.

Comment: Menciono que fue migración porque antes funcionaba luego migraron y ahora no! mas alla de eso no se que pueda revisar el el codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solventado. el link que adicione anteriormente no me funcionaba porque lo aplicaba al servidor de comunicación y no al de respuesta solo ejecute el comando aspnet_regiis.exe -iru